# Difference between region adapter and region behavior?

Tags: mvvm, prism

I have used region adapters a lot but cannot find a good use case for region behavior. Both seem to fit in the context of adding additional behavior to a region. How are they different ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Region Adapter** is meant to adapt a control that cannot be marked as a region (a control that does not inherit from `ItemsControl`, `ContentControl` or `Selector`, in Silverlight also `TabControl`).
 For example, if you wanted to use a Ribbon control as a region you would create a region adapter for it.
Its goal would be to determine what to do when a view is added to it, by managing its Children/Content property accordingly.

**Region Behavior** adds functionality to all regions. A sample use of a region behavior can be found [here](http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2009/12/23/memory-leak-removing-view-with-child-regions-in-prism-v2/).

Comment: Can't I do the same in Adapt method ? thats my confusion. How would I pick and choose between the two.

Comment: there's probably a way to get the functionality pushed in anywhere you want. you could use the event aggregator for intra-module communication as well, but that is not its main goal.

Comment: The link is **dead**, I found [this link](http://southworks.com/blog/2011/11/10/regions-inside-datatemplates-in-prism-v4-using-a-region-behavior/). I think this is really the same blog we want to refer to, but the link has been changed, Is it ?